# Building custom SQL schema in strapi

Tags: strapi

I am using strapi for my project, and I'd like to customize the default schema and add some constraints.

Is there some strapi way to implement a custom table with multi-field key or some advanced constraints?

Answer (score 0):

you can customize the model by modifing the modelname.settings.json file.
https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#models.

You can also implement policies to set up constraints.
https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#policies

Comment: This is not what I had asked. Constraints set up via policies are not atomic. I've been looking to extend the actual SQL schema.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting response to my question at strapi community forum:

> Not through Strapi itself yet we are looking into this for the v4
> (once we have a public RFC ready we will let everyone know to give
> time to review it).
>
> But you can apply them at the database level manually for most cases
> and they shouldn’t be broken by Strapi, certain constraints can’t be
> applied at the database level (specifically unique as an example with
> the I18N beta) but keys for example shouldn’t cause any issues.

Thus, what I ended up doing is hooking to [bootstrap](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html#bootstrap) function and applying schema modifications there.